# Multiple checkin / checkout datepickers?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a datepicker with a check in and check out date that I've grabbed from the example website: [LINK](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)

My question is how do I make this work when I have multiple check in check out forms without having to repeat the entire code replacing the class names?

Her is a plunkr: [LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/rhXZFPPlylkrLA00odrU?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the code in a function and call it multiple times:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ui97SsODrcbwdK9jo8PD?p=preview

Call the new function this way in the load function:

```
checkInOut($('.dpd1a'), $('.dpd2a'), now);
checkInOut($('.dpd1b'), $('.dpd2b'), now);
```

Wrap with this and change the direct references to the elements to `inEl` and `outEl`.

```
var checkInOut = function(inEl, outEl, now) {
    ... existing code is almost exactly the same ...
};
```

The values of the variables `checkIn` and `checkOut` are set during the setup and preserved in the closure. But they are only used inside the function and each time you call the function, a new set of values are set up.